# Scrapy Request callback method never called

Tags: python-2.7, request, scrapy

I am building a CrawlSpider using Scrapy 0.22.2 for Python 2.7.3 and am having problems with Requests, where the callback method that I specify is never called. Here is a snippet from my parsing method that initiates a Request within a elif block:

```
elif current_status == "Superseded":
        #Need to do more work here. Have to check whether there is a replacement unit available. If there isn't, download whatever outline is there
        # We need to look for a <td> element which contains "Is superseded by " and follow that link
        updated_unit = hxs.xpath('/html/body/div[@id="page"]/div[@id="layoutWrapper"]/div[@id="twoColLayoutWrapper"]/div[@id="twoColLayoutLeft"]/div[@class="layoutContentWrapper"]/div[@class="outer"]/div[@class="fieldset"]/div[@class="display-row"]/div[@class="display-row"]/div[@class="display-field-info"]/div[@class="t-widget t-grid"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[contains(., "Is superseded by ")]/a')
        # need child element a
        updated_unit_link = updated_unit.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
        updated_url = "http://training.gov.au" + updated_unit_link
        print "\033[0;31mSuperceded by "+updated_url+"\033[0m" # prints in Red for superseded, need to follow this link to current
        yield Request(url=updated_url, callback='sortSuperseded', dont_filter=True)

def sortSuperseded(self, response):
    print "\033[0;35mtest callback called\033[0m"
```

There are no errors when I execute this and the url is OK, but sortSuperseded is never called as I never see the 'test callback called' printed in the console.

The url I am extracting is also within the domain that I specify for my CrawlSpider.

```
allowed_domains = ["training.gov.au"]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you share your console log? Also, try using `callback=self.sortSuperseded` instead of the method name

Comment: Are you sure it ever gets to the `yield Request(url=updated_url, callback='sortSuperseded')`line? Put there `1/0` or a breakpoint (`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`) to be sure.

Comment: Hi paul t. and warwaruk, thanks for the replies. I got it working by changing the call to `yield Request(updated_url, callback=self.sortSuperseded)`. Removing the quotes did the trick, I was confused by the need to wrap callbacks in quotes when specifying rules. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Quotes are not required around the callback method name. Change the line:

```
yield Request(url=updated_url, callback='sortSuperseded', dont_filter=True)
```

to

```
yield Request(updated_url, callback=self.sortSuperseded, dont_filter=True)
```

Comment: I added this answer based on the comment from the OP, CrackpotTenure, and removed the word "SOLVED" from the title.